# counting comparisons shell sort will use to sort list

Tags: sorting

How many comparisons will Shell sort use to sort the following list if gaps of `3` then `1` are used?

```
[9, 3, 10, 2, 7, 1, 0, 11, 6, 5, 8, 4]
```

So I used shell sort (by hand) and split it into `3` groups then sorted and counted `9` comparisons. But then I got confused with the next part with insertion sort to finally sort the list and counting the comparisons there?